# Load DLL with parameters

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio, dll

I need to delete every single function from my project (VB.Net) and place them in separate DLLs. For example, i have a function that creates a text file and appends text to it. I need a solution that will load my AppendToTextFile.DLL with params just like a function works.

At this time my function accepts two parameters like

```
AppendToTextFile("C:\test\textFile.txt", "text to be appended")
```

Does anyone know how to load a custom DLL with params like the function above?

Comment: DLLs don't have parameters. Methods have parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create your custom DLL.
- Then add it as reference to your project.
- Call you function and use it like this :

  ```
   Dim mydll As New MyCustomeDll
   mydll.AppendToTextFile("C:\test\textFile.txt", "text to be appended")
  ```

That's all.